# Encountering RecursionError when trying to delete multiple text channels with the same channel name

Tags: python, recursion, discord.py

I want to delete multiple text channels with the same name in a server

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def delete_channel(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        if(channel.name.startswith("remove")):
            await delete_channel(channel)
```

Here is the error I encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling same `delete_channel` function over and over (recursion), if you want to delete a channel use the `.delete()` method

```py
await channel.delete()
```